# jquery .hover and .delay

Tags: jquery

I want to prevent accidental activation of tooltips on hover by using .delay and .queue.

It works, except that I don't know how to stop executing the queue when you mouseout (leave the area)

```
$('.has_tooltip').hover(
  function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('highlight').delay(400).queue(function(next){
      $(this).children('.tooltip').show(); next();
    });
  }, 
  function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('highlight').children('.tooltip').fadeOut(200)
  }
);
```

Comment: I think you're looking for [.clearqueue](http://api.jquery.com/clearQueue/)

Comment: thank you! I initially found .dequeue, which had the opposite effect..

Comment: use .stop() while you are moving out.

Comment: Btw hoverintent is a great plugin for that: http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html

Comment: use .stop() on mouse out function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Gidon said, http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html should work just fine.